Reconstructing a scheme from its quotient stack
Let $X/S$ be a scheme over a base $S$, with a group action by a nice group $G/S$ (typically $G/S$ affine smooth).
Can we reconstruct $X$ from its quotient stack $[X/G]$?
It seems that we can expect $X$ to be isomorphic to $[X/G] \times_{BG} S$ where $BG=[S/G]$ is the classifying stack. Indeed, a $T$-point in $[X/G]$ is a $G$-torsor $T' \to T$ with a $G$-equivariant map to $X$, and if we want this point to be in the fibered product above, this imposes $T'$ to be isomorphic to the trivial torsor $T'=G \times T$, and the data of the equivariant map from $T'$ to $X$ is equivalent to the data of a map from $T$ to $X$.
The reason that I am confused, is as follows. Let's look at an elliptic curve $E/k: y^2=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)$ over a field $k$ of characteristic different from two, and the action of $\mu_2$ given by $P \mapsto -P$. Then the stack quotient $[E/\mu_2]$ should be the stacky (tame) projective line $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ with stacky points with stabilizer $\mu_2$ at the ramification points $(a_1:1), (a_2:1), (a_3:1), (1:0)$.
Here I am using https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.04657 Lemma 5.3.10 to represent a stacky curve just from its coarse space and the stabilizer of its stacky points.
But now if I take a quadratic twist $E'/k: \alpha y^2=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)$, with $\alpha$ not a square in $k$, then $[E'/\mu_2]$ has exactly the same ramification as $[E/\mu_2]$, so we should have an isomorphism $[E/\mu_2] \simeq [E'/\mu_2]$ over $k$ by the result above. But $E'$ is only isomorphic to $E$ over a quadratic extension $k'/k$ (which incidentally is an étale $\mu_2$-torsor). So it seems that the quotient stack $[E/\mu_2]$ can only reconstruct $E$ over an étale extension of $k$.

Is it possible that the stacks are the same but the maps to $BG$ ($G=\mu_2$ in your example) are different?

Oh of course, that has to be what happens. Let's take $k$ a finite field, so we have two possible quadratic twists $E$ and $E'$. If $x \in \mathbb{P}^1$ is not in the ramification, the isomorphism has to be the map that sends the $\mu_2$ torsor $\pi_E^{-1}(x)$ to $\pi_{E'}^{-1}(x)$. But only one of these two $\mu_2$-torsor is trivial, the other splits over a quadratic extension of $k$, so indeed the map to $B\mu_2$ is not the same. Thanks!

More simply, consider a nontrivial étale double cover $X\to Y$ of connected schemes, and take $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $Y=[X/G]$ where $G$ acts on $X$ by the obvious involution. So we have an isomorphism $[X/G]\cong[(Y\amalg Y)/G]$ while $X\not\cong Y\amalg Y$.
